# Emails will not be deleted by Mail.app

Tags: macos, mail.app, imap

All of us in the office use the same (remote) email server (via IMAP) but only some of us have this issue:

Emails are deleted in Mail.app and go to trash

After sometime the email reappears as unread email in the main mailbox

Colleague with this problem has an iPhone and Mac OSX laptop.

I don't have this issue and have an Android phone but also have OSX laptop.

Where do we need to look to sort this?

Comment: Are the deletion and reappearance both taking place on the laptop, or is one on the phone and one on the laptop? If the latter, which happens where?

Comment: What are the IMAP settings in Mail.app for the laptop in question.

Answer (score 1):

Recommended settings for IMAP with mail.app

In

> Mail.app
>
> Preferences
>
> Accounts
>
> Select the account in question
>
> set Mailbox Behavior

see sample

[image: mailbox settings]